# SQL query (postgreSQL), jsonb array column

Tags: sql, postgresql

i have a table like this:

```
CREATE TABLE ads (id SERIAL, category_ids JSONB, ad_type_ids JSONB, market JSONB, main_category_id integer, approved boolean, status boolean, is_classified boolean, expire_at timestamp(0), refreshed_at timestamp(0));
```

this is a simplified snippet from a larger query:

```
select distinct ads.id, ads.category_ids
    from ads
             inner join (select *
                         from (select jsonb_array_elements('[
                           14,
                           5,
                           19
                         ]') as options) k) k on ads.category_ids @> k.options
```

category_ids is a *JSONB* column, contains up to 6 values in average for each row in the ads table.
this inner array for matching can reach up to thousands of values and i need to match a single value to get the record.

e.g: matching array is [14, 5, 19], records having this in category_ids column are a match for me:

```
[14],
[14,5],
[14, 10]
```

but when this matching array reach thousands of values, the query takes too much time.
i tried creating a gin index on category_ids like so:

```
CREATE INDEX category_ids_index ON ads USING gin (category_ids)
```

and it did not solve the problem.
this is the full query i'm using:

```
select id, is_classified
              from (select distinct ads.id, ads.is_classified, ads.refreshed_at
                  from ads
                           inner join (select *
                                       from (select jsonb_array_elements('[
                                     14,
                                     5
                                   ]') as options) k) k on ads.ad_type_ids @> k.options
                       inner join (select *
                                   from (select jsonb_array_elements('[
                                     68,
                                     68,
                                     126,
                                     370,
                                     371,
                                     372,
                                     373,
                                     12135,
                                     12134
                                   ]') as options) y) y
                                  on ads.category_ids @> y.options and ads.market @> '[59]' and ads.status = true and
                                     (ads.approved = true or ads.approved ISNULL) and ads.expire_at > '2021-08-29 10:44:55' and ads.main_category_id = 60 and ads.is_classified = 'false'
              order by ads.refreshed_at desc
              limit 4 offset 0) q
```

=====

UPDATE:

i noticed that when i remove the order by clause, the query run in milli sec !

i tried creating an index on the *refreshed_at* column, and it did not help though !

Comment: Avoid storing arrays of identifiers in a JSON.

Comment: thanks for the tip, please read the update in the post.